# Nexus devices not recognized by adb

Tags: adb, nexus-7, nexus-5, nexus-4

Adb does not recognize my Nexus devices but does recognize my Samsung Tab 2 7 inch tablet.

```
   C:\Users\Allen Edwards\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
   List of devices attached
   c0808e004a14c2f device
```

The device recognized is the Samsung.  There are also a Nexus 5x, Nexus 4, Nexus 7, and Nexus S connected.

In Windows Explorer I can browse the Samsung, Nexus 5x and Nexus 7 but not the other two.

All have USB debugging and are connected as MTP or as USB for File Transfer in the case of the Nexus 5x.

The Google USB Driver shows up as up to date in the SDK Manager and also comes back as up to date if I try and manually update it from a fresh download.  ADB shows up as up to date when I try and update it.

I uninstalled the Nexus 5x USB driver from Device Manager and when I plugged it back in the same driver was installed which interestingly has a date of 2006. How can that be right?

It would seem logical that somewhere I have a Samsung usb driver that is interfering with the Google usb driver but I have the latest Google usb driver downloaded and point all the update drivers to that and I get that Windows says it is up to date, MTP USB Device.

The Googling I have done typically suggests things that I have done, like checking USB Debugging, or updating the drivers.

I thought perhaps Windows was getting the wrong driver for the Nexus 5x so I thought I would uninstall it and manually install it but as soon as I uninstall it, the icon vanishes and upon refreshing for new hardware, the same driver is installed.

Any ideas of things I can try?

Comment: I deleted the Google USB driver from SDL Manager and reinstalled it and now I can see my nexus devices and the Samsung in adb.  I guess I should have tried deleting them there instead of Device Manager but every post I saw talked about Device Manager.  I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall USB driver using SDK Manager instead of Device Manager.  Device Manager just reinstalls the same driver on the next connection of the device.